# Saving/Loading Data with NSUserDefaults (cocos2d iphone)

Tags: iphone, load, cocos2d-iphone, save, nsuserdefaults

I have an Upgrades scene where the user can upgrade different attributes of the game, and I want that information to be saved. For example, when the user spends 1000 points to upgrade the mag by 5, I want that information to be saved for the next launch of the app. I've been told NSUserDefaults is a good way to do this. Is this the right way of correctly saving/loading the mag int?

```
-(void)plusFiveMag:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:NSNumber numberWithInt:mag forKey:@"mag"];
    mag += 5; 
}   
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:NSNumber numberWithInt:mag forKey:@"mag"];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using accessors makes this all so much easier. Using accessors means you never have to worry about how `mag` is stored internally, so you can transparently store it in `NSUserDefaults` rather than in an ivar.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) NSUInteger mag;

NSString * const kMagDefaultsKey = @"mag";

- (NSUInteger)mag {
  return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kMagDefaultsKey];
}

- (void)setMag:(NSUInteger)value {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:value forKey:kMagDefaultsKey];
}

- (void)addFiveToMag:(id)sender {
  self.mag = self.mag + 5;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look much simpler than the other method. Will this work if I need to use 'mag' in other places as well?

Comment: That's what I mean by it's simpler. The other approaches force you to repeat the "set the ivar and also set the NSUserDefaults" every place you touch mag. This approach puts it in one place (the accessor). As long as you always use "self.mag" it will transparently do the right thing. If you ever change how you store mag, you fix it in one place, not every place that uses mag. Moreover, this gets rid of all the timing concerns involved with initializing in viewDidLoad (this can run a long time after the object is created, and can run multiple times).

Comment: The thing is that I created 'mag' as an int in another class. Does it have to be changed to NSNumber, and do I have to do anything special to import it into this class?

Comment: NSUInteger is just a platform-independent unsigned int. It is not an object. It's just a typedef, and generally what you should use in place of "unsigned." The signed equivalent is NSInteger. If you replace "NSUInteger" with "int" above, it will also work.

Comment: How do I import it from class 'A' to class 'B'?

Comment: You declare `mag` to be an `NSUInteger` assign-property in A.h and import that into B.m.

Comment: Yes, how do I go about importing it into B? `@property (copy)`?
Or `#import "A.h"` and then do ____________?

Comment: `#import "A.h"`. That's it. mag is a property on A, correct? Perhaps I don't know what you mean by "import" here. Importing is just telling the compiler the interface of another class so that you can make calls to it. Any public properties for a class should be declared in the header of that class.

Comment: Ok so to verify If I just #imported it I could start using mag in my B class?

Comment: Also, do I have to do anything else in the addFiveToMag method? It will just save that mag number automatically?

Comment: And for the line `

NSString * const kMagDefaultsKey = @"mag";
` I get the error _expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__ attribute __' before '=' token_.


Also says kMagDefaultsKey is undeclared

Comment: Regarding `addFiveToMag`, any method that uses the accessors (self.mag) will automatically read and write to NSUserDefaults. You don't have to do anything special anywhere else. Just use the accessors and get rid of the `mag` ivar.

Comment: kMagDefaultsKey should be declared in the .m file, outside of any method. Is that how you're doing it. You can also prefix it with `static`.

Comment: OK Thanks for the continuous support.

Answer (score 0):

Store it like this:

```
-(void)plusFiveMag:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:mag forKey:@"mag"];
    mag += 5; 
}
```

To get it you would have to use:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int mag = [defaults integerforKey:@"mag"];
}
```

Comment: That's not enough to tell where the error occured. Not neccessarly with the code above. Insert the console output. By the way how do you create the mag ivar?

Comment: That's probably the issue. I create it in the .h of another class. The problem is that I imported it wrong, I guess. I @class'd the class, and then did `@property (nonatomic, assign) int mag;
`

Comment: Also changing `setObject` to `setInteger` gives me a warning "Passing argument 1 of 'setInteger:forKey:' makes integer from pointer without a cast